# Export sql results to JSON file

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I'm trying to modify a php script to write to a JSON file when it is run every 15 minutes, and then overwrite the updated results. The script I have is doing this in the database (inserting and updating on duplicate) but my code for the JSON file is not working quite right.

When I manually export to JSON from workbench, I get this (which is what I want):

```
                [
                {
                    "ID" : 1,
                    "Extension" : 7218,
                    "ExtID" : 35302,
                    "Total_Talk_Time_seconds" : 11,
                    "Total_Talk_Time_minutes" : 0.18,
                    "Total_Inbound" : 0,
                    "Total_Outbound" : 1,
                    "Missed_Calls" : 0,
                    "Total_Calls" : null,
                    "Date_of_report" : "2017-08-15",
                    "Time_of_report" : "2017-08-15 08:58:31"
                },
                {
                    "ID" : 2,
                    "Extension" : 7306,
                    "ExtID" : 35370,
                    "Total_Talk_Time_seconds" : 762,
                    "Total_Talk_Time_minutes" : 12.7,
                    "Total_Inbound" : 4,
                    "Total_Outbound" : 0,
                    "Missed_Calls" : 3,
                    "Total_Calls" : null,
                    "Date_of_report" : "2017-08-15",
                    "Time_of_report" : "2017-08-15 08:58:31"
                },
                {
                    "ID" : 3,
                    "Extension" : 7358,
                    "ExtID" : 35278,
                    "Total_Talk_Time_seconds" : 41,
                    "Total_Talk_Time_minutes" : 0.68,
                    "Total_Inbound" : 0,
                    "Total_Outbound" : 0,
                    "Missed_Calls" : 0,
                    "Total_Calls" : null,
                    "Date_of_report" : "2017-08-15",
                    "Time_of_report" : "2017-08-15 08:58:31"
                }
            ]
```

But when I run my actual PHP script below, I get This:

```
    {"extension":"7358","RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID":"35278","Total_Talk_Time_seconds":"41","Total_Talk_Time_minutes":"0.68","Total_Outbound":"0","Total_Inbound":"0","Total_Missed":"0","Total_Calls":"0","time":"2017-08-15 10:05:07","date":"2017-08-15"}
```

So, it's writing the results finally, but it's only one of 6 records, and it's the third in the table, so it doesn't really make sense to me why it would pull the third record as only one record. It's also not formatted in JSON by giving a new line to each value, but JSON is very foreign to me in general.

The PHP Script runs without errors and inserts into my database correctly, I just have to have this script write the results to a JSON file and overwrite when run every 15 minutes.

```
$data = mysqli_query($conn, " SELECT c.extension
                          ,RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID
                          , sum(Duration) AS Total_Talk_Time_seconds
                          , round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) AS Total_Talk_Time_minutes
                          , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) AS Total_Outbound
                          , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0)) AS Total_Inbound
                          , sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) AS Total_Missed
                          , count(DISTINCT b.NOTABLECALLID) AS total_calls
                          , NOW() AS time
                          , curdate() AS date
                      FROM cdrdb.session a
                      INNER JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
                           ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
                      INNER join cdrdb.mxuser c
                           ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
                      WHERE b.ts >= curdate()
                      AND c.extension IN (7295,7306,7218,7247,7330,7000,7358)
                      group by c.extension");


                      $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn2, "Insert into jfi.ambitionphone(Extension, ExtID, Total_Talk_Time_seconds,
                       Total_Talk_Time_minutes,Total_Outbound, Total_Inbound,
                       Missed_Calls, Total_Calls, Time_of_report,Date_of_report  )
                         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                         ON duplicate key update
                         Total_Talk_Time_seconds = values(Total_Talk_Time_seconds),
                         Total_Talk_Time_minutes = values(Total_Talk_Time_minutes),
                         Total_Outbound = values(Total_Outbound),
                         Total_Inbound = values(Total_Inbound),
                         Missed_calls = values(Missed_Calls),
                         Total_Calls = values(Total_Calls),
                         Time_of_report = values(Time_of_report),
                         Date_of_report = values(Date_of_report)") or die(mysqli_error($conn2));


 foreach ($data as $d) {

      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"iiidiiiiss", $d['extension'], $d['RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID'],
          $d['Total_Talk_Time_seconds'], $d['Total_Talk_Time_minutes'],
          $d['Total_Outbound'], $d['Total_Inbound'], $d['Total_Missed'], $d['Total_Calls'],
          $d['time'], $d['date']) or die(mysqli_error($conn2));
     mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_error($conn2));

 $ambitionJSONdata = json_encode($d);
     file_put_contents('ambitionLog.json', $ambitionJSONdata);
 }
```

Is there something I can do here to get the output like it is when I do the manual export?

Comment: You're currently overwriting the file on each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently overwriting the file on each iteration. Create a main array to store each iteration in:

```
// Create the main array
$content = [];

while ($d = mysqli_fetch_array($data, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"iiidiiiiss", $d['extension'], $d['RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID'],
          $d['Total_Talk_Time_seconds'], $d['Total_Talk_Time_minutes'],
          $d['Total_Outbound'], $d['Total_Inbound'], $d['Total_Missed'], $d['Total_Calls'],
          $d['time'], $d['date']) or die(mysqli_error($conn2));
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_error($conn2));

    // Store the current row in the main array
    $content[] = $d;
}

// Store the main array that contains all the rows
file_put_contents('ambitionLog.json', json_encode($content));
```

Comment: Thank you, that totally makes sense now why it would overwrite. I moved it in the loop to see what would change and didn't think about that. Thank you, trying this now.

Comment: Ok, the updated answer ran successfully, but now this is my file:

{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}

So no more values at all, just these attributes

Comment: So then, I should have kept it like you had it by creating the array?

Comment: @TomN. Updated the answer again

Comment: Ok, the logic of that totally makes sense, but when I run it I get empty square brackets, []

Comment: @TomN. Last attempt. I also changed the loop to actually fetch each row

Comment: Yes that got it, thank you. I believe that's what you put the first time, but I didn't have a chance to try it before the edit. It does process as one big block with no real JSON formatting but I can figure that out. Thanks@

Comment: @TomN. What do you mean by "no real JSON formatting"? Check the update ;-)

Comment: Oh no I did use the update and it works, I just mean how JSON usually indents each record, and then line breaks/indents each value beneath it. When it's not brokent by line, the linter in my ide eventually stops highlighting due to format. But I think I can create parameters in my code that break the lines, like the formatting in my first code block where I manually export from workbench

Comment: @TomN. If you want the json to look nice, use `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`: `json_encode($content, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`. That will add line breaks and indents.

Comment: Wow, that was easy! Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score -1):

just use this line in your out put area
 echo json_encode $your_final_array;

Comment: How does this solve the actual issue? There are more to it than just "echo"

Comment: Yes, I need to take the array and encode it into JSON and write to .json file